# Creating SVG graphics using a server side script (PHP)

Tags: php, javascript, html, svg

Is there a way to generate an HTML file using a PHP script which has an SVG embedded where the SVG itself is dynamically generated by the PHP script?

Basically, I want to display a dynamically generated SVG image to a client but `<embed>`, `<object>` as well as `<iframe>` only refer to external sources while PHP generates the current HTML page only (and not the external sources)

Further, is there a Javascript solution possible where I add SVG elements in the current DOM one by one?

Comment: Please explain the downvote. I am badly stuck in a project and if this is a duplicate, I would love to find the solution.

Comment: Really not sure why this was downvoted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try linking to your php file like this: `<object href=svg_generator.php> <!-- other attributes necessary for embedding svg not listed here -->`

Comment: ohh.. :) missed that one out completely. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can have a look at raphael http://raphaeljs.com/ a wonderful javascript library which make easy to manipulate svg objects in a cross-browser way.

I am sure that it will help you a lot